# Effectively retrieving BLOB XML from database using Java

Tags: xml, database, apache, blob, jdom-2

I am trying to read XML file details from Sun Identity Manager database using below snippet

```
            String xmlTxt="";
            ArrayList<String> xmlList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BLOB blob=null;
            OracleConnection conn=null;
            OraclePreparedStatement stmt = null;
            OracleResultSet rs = null;
            GZIPInputStream gStream = null;
            log.debug("Initializing DB connection...");

                try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                conn=(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUserName, dbPassword);           
                stmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareCall("SELECT XML FROM TASK WHERE TYPE='WorkItem'");
                rs = (OracleResultSet) stmt.executeQuery();

                    while(rs.next()){
                        blob = rs.getBLOB(columnLabel);
                    if(!blob.isEmptyLob())
                        gStream = new GZIPInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream());
                    if(gStream.available()>0)
                        xmlTxt = IOUtils.toString(gStream,columnEncoding);                          
                        xmlList.add(xmlTxt);
                    }
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
                    //Handle errors for Class.forName
                    log.error("ClassNotFoundException " + cnf.getMessage());
                    log.error("ClassNotFoundException " + cnf);     
                }
                catch (SQLException se) {
                //Handle errors for JDBC
                log.error("SQLException " +se.getMessage());
                log.error("SQLException " + se);
                }
                catch (IOException ie) {
                //Handle errors for I/O
                log.error("IOException " +ie.getMessage());
                log.error("IOLException " + ie);
                }
                catch (OutOfMemoryError E){
                    log.error("OutOfMemoryError Encountered :"+ Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
                }
                finally{
                    try {
                        if(rs!=null)
                        rs.close();
                        if(stmt!=null)
                        stmt.close();
                        if(blob!=null)
                        blob.free();
                        if(conn!=null)
                        conn.close();
                        } 
                    catch (SQLException se) {
                        //Handle errors for JDBC
                        log.error("SQLException during close " +se.getMessage());
                        log.error("SQLException during close" + se);
                        }
                }
                log.debug("End of DB Operation");               
            return xmlList;
```

Currently I am testing it in our Dev environment where the records are in 100's and average size of each blob data is 2 MB. Also I could see consumption of heap size is huge when there is steady increase in total records. My current Java heap  size is Xmx512m -Xms64m and in prod we have nearly 1.5 million records to process so wondering how much heap size would be required.

I usually get out of memory error for below line

xmlTxt = IOUtils.toString(gStream,columnEncoding);

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Please advise if there are any other better way we can optimize the code to improve performance.

Comment: You're streaming the entire contents of your database table  into memory. So, one way to optimize your code would be to, um, not do that.

Comment: To answer your question about how much heap space you'll need in prod: I'm estimating it's gonna be somewhere around the 3000GB mark.

Comment: Hmm.. But I have all my required data in the BLOB column only so have to retrieve that anyhow and process it with our business logic...

Comment: It's not about the one BLOB. It's about storing potentially one and a half million of them in a list (`xmlList`). Can't you implement your logic in a streaming fashion?

Comment: Thanks Robby. I am able to change my logic using streaming option for entire project and that has reduced the heap size to greater extent :-)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the data from table in streaming fashion rather than copying it to memory as string/array list.